# Customising nbconvert with jupyterhub

Tags: jupyterhub, nbconvert

I have a jupyter hubinstance running using the sudospawner to start individual notebook instances.  Mostly this is working very well.  However, I need to add various configuration commands to nbconvert so that html downloading from the notebook works correctly (hidden codecells, python markdown etc).

There appears to be no information about where the sudospawned jupyter instance picks up the nbconvert configuration from.  The `jupyterhub_config.py` file is in a directory `~jupyter/etc/jupyter` and so I have tried putting the `jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` and `jupyter_nbconvert_config.json` files there and they don't seem to be read.

Is there anything else I can try or can somebody point me to the right bit of the documentation?

Comment: Try `jupyter_notebook_config` instead of `jupyter_nbconvert_config`.

Answer (score 0):

It is picked from ~/.jupyter . If you are new to linux ~/ indicates your home folder, so the full path would be /home/< your username >/.jupyter

Comment: Jupyter notebook generates its list of export options automatically so I am not sure how to customize it. In any case, it will not use `jupyter_nbconvert_config` but `jupyter_notebook_config`. `jupyter_nbconvert_config` will only be picked at the CLI with nbconvert.